# Importing a module into a custom command

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have the following Django project:

```
/ # Project dir
/myapp # App dir
/myapp/views.py # views file
/myapp/mymodule.py # a Python module
/myapp/management/commands/mycommand.py # command file
```

In the views file, I can import `mymodule.py` by simply writing `import mymodule` in `views.py`. However, if I do the same in `mycommand.py`, I get the error: `ImportError: no module named mymodule`. I know that to import a model, I can write `from myapp.models import mymodel`, but `mymodule` is not a model, it is a separate Python module. So, how do I import this moduel into my command file?

Answer (score 2):

Thats because of where mymodule is in relation to all of your other files.

If you type

```
from myapp import mymodule
```

In mycommand.py as long as you have set up your `__init__.py` files correctly in myapp and are using a setup.py file you should be fine. The [modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) documentation has more information on this

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are unable to do this means your myapp folder is not in the python's `sys.path`. The reason it worked in `views.py` is because `mymodule.py` is in the current directory of `views.py`
Assuming your Project dir (/) is in the python's `sys.path`:

1. Add a file `__init__.py` in myapp directory. This file can be blank.
2. Then you can do `import myapp.mymodule` or `from myapp import mymodule`

The same logic applies for n levels deep. If you have `myapp/myappdir1/myappdir2/myfile.py` you can do  `import myapp.myappdir1.myappdir2.myfile` assuming each of these have `__init__.py` file in them.

Check https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path for python's module search path